# suppressing URLs in footnotes but not bibliography

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, biber, urls

I am using Biber and the verbose IBID style setting to generate my footnotes. Here is my bibliography settings

```
\usepackage[citestyle=verbose-ibid, bibstyle=authoryear, backend=biber, labeldate]{biblatex}
```

Some of my book entries in the bib file contain URL data (e.g. the Google book reference). I like the fact that these are showing up in the bibliography section at the back of the document, but I do not want them showing up in the full version of the first citation of a work.

Is there some way to de-activate URL printing in the main matter, but not in the back matter, e.g. by redeclaring some macro?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: I thought the question was too simple, but I can see now how that is in general the more helpful thing to do, esp once you know the file inclusion trick that @lockstep showcased. Will do so the next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{url}}` to your preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}

\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{url}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  url = {http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example

Some text \autocite{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 You're always one of the best with `biblatex` ;-)

Comment: @karlkoeller Especially with respect to easy questions. ;-)

Comment: This does the opposite for me :\ Suppresses the url in the bibliography but not the footnotes

Comment: should this method also work with other fields? I have a similar issue. I would like to have the field {ecli} not in the footnotes but in the bibliography. \AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{ecli} doesn't work. should it?