# Print field (url) in bibliography but not in citation?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Is it possible to print a certain field in the bibliography while omitting it in the (footnote) citations?

For example:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=verbose-trad1,natbib=true,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{x-mendeley.bib}

...

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}} 
\printbibliography
```

Prints this citation and bibliography:

[image]
[image]

I can get the url, isbn etc. in there by using:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=verbose-note,natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

This is what I want for the bibliography, but I don't want all these long urls etc in the  footnote citations.

[image]

Is there a way to differentiate between the two?
And could I for example add the isbn's to the citation but not the url?

Comment: You can use `\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=verbose-note,natbib=true]{biblatex}` and `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{url}}` to display the URL in the bibliography, but not the citation.

Comment: Great. Would you say your question is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/215503/35864, then?

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry, couldn't find that one

Comment: Don't worry about that. It's always easier to find the duplicate question if you know the answer.